# How to stop disks from being automagically mounted on boot?

Tags: boot, mount, raid, fstab, btrfs

I have a btrfs filesystem RAIDed across several disks. The machine is connected via USB to an external hard-drive bay where three disks live.

In my `fstab` I have a mount entry for one of the disks and the path (`/dev/sdb`). However, during boots Ubuntu mounts *all* of the disks `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`. I'd like to stop Ubuntu from mounting the other disks during boot. Is there anyway to disable auto-mounting of attached disks *on boot* with the exception of the ones explicitly in `/etc/fstab`?

Here are the contents of `fstab`

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=eb80bbb0-7b27-4b7c-b041-639cbcae1c77 /           ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0e0c01be-7545-449c-86a8-60309d016534 none        swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb /media/xbmc    btrfs   defaults  0 1
```

When the machine boots I find something like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       294G   35G  245G  13% /
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           791M  892K  790M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  1.6M  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdc        4.6T  1.3T  2.6T  34% /media/0868831f-d234-4172-aeab-640e580190d0
/dev/sdd        4.6T  1.3T  2.6T  34% /media/0956647d-a558-2218-febt-559a647221r5
/dev/sdb        4.6T  1.3T  2.6T  34% /media/xbmc
```

Comment: Do the required lines in your fstab have the `noauto` option?

Comment: @jippie I want *everything* in `fstab` to mount. Ubuntu is mounting disks that *aren't* in `fstab`, which is the problem.

Comment: Is the `ARRAY` line for this BTRFS array still present in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`?

Comment: @Samik It's not using mdadm, it's using BTRFS's filesystem array. It's just a bunch of disks attached to the machine connected together by btrfs

Comment: Sorry if I didn't get it clearly. To be clarified, is `/dev/sdb` mentioned in `/etc/fstab` a part of the multi-disk-spanning BTRFS array? And is Ubuntu mounting all the disks even if they are _not_ in the BTRFS array or `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @Samik Only ONE disk is mentioned if fstab, all disks are being mounted during boot. My question contains the contents of `fstab` and `mount`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3646/discussion-between-samik-and-marco-ceppi)

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Those disks are being mounted by a udev rule in `/lib/udev/rules.d`, you need to find it, change the correct line and modify it to ignore sdc and sdd. If I find it I will post a more complete thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `noauto` option for `mount` lets the user to mount the device/partition concerned only explicitely, not with `mount -a` or not on boot if mentioned in `/etc/fstab`'s option column for the concerned device. If you can add `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`(or their UUIDs) in `/etc/fstab` and provide the `noauto` option in option(4th) column they won't be mounted automatically.

(see the man page for `mount` or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab#Common_options_to_all_filesystems))