# How to hide btrfs devices in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, btrfs

I've got a btrfs file system consisting of 3 devices and using raid1. The file system contains one subvolume "home" which is defined in the fstab and mounted at "/home". fstab entry looks like this:

```
/dev/sdb3   /home   btrfs   device=/dev/sdb3,device=/dev/sdc,device=/dev/sda,compress=lzo,subvol=home   0   0
```

When I open nautilus in 12.04, it lists both "secondary" btrfs devices (sdc and sda) on the left side under "Devices". I can actually mount btrfs system once again when clicking on the icons.

How do I hide those icons in the nautilus?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145938/how-to-stop-disks-from-being-automagically-mounted-on-boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got rid of that entry by adding a fstab entry with a `/mnt` mountpoint, that would be:

```
/dev/sdc1       /mnt/nonexistent               btrfs   noauto        0       0
/dev/sdb1       /mnt/nonexistent               btrfs   noauto        0       0
```

for you.

(With some [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828868/510711) from Stackoverflow )