# How to control NTFS drives access/mount from Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, files, ntfs

I have installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10 and no, when I run `Files` program, I see all `NTFS` drives listed at LHS panel of a window:

[image]

When I click drive, it is mounted under `/media/`, but until I click, it doesn't mounted. It's irrational. I can't rely on any path on `NTFS` drive since it doesn't exist until I click it in separate application. Also, some drives I don't wan't to be listed at all, like drive `C`.

So, how to completely disable this feature of `Files` program and mound `NTFS` drives permanently?

Comment: Configure them in `/etc/fstab`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions

Comment: @ByteCommander will drives disappear from `Files` then?

Comment: Yes, only "removable" or "manually mountable" devices show up in Nautilus' sidebar. Automatically mounted drives don't. But I think even if you just configure it in `/etc/fstab` with the `noauto` option to not mount it automatically at boot time, it will still not show up.

Comment: The last question: how to remove drive C from both fstab and nautilus?

Comment: Just configuring in fstab as noauto should be enough. It won't get ever mounted that way unless you explicitly command it to do so. And IIRC it should not show up as mountable device in Nautilus. See also https://askubuntu.com/q/164412/367990

Comment: Actually, in some system settings apps you can just set checkpoints, at least, to either always mount a specific drive, or to mount all removable devices. At the very least it's possible on `systemsettings` of KDE.